# Alternative scalar product for vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Simple question. Is there a product between two vectors, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ in which
$$ \mathbf{AB}=A_iB_j$$
Where the subindex is a sum for all components of the vectors. 
Also is the definition $\mathbf{[A,B]}=\mathbf{AB}-\mathbf{BA}$ correctly expressed?

Comment: So you want ${\bf AB}=\sum_i\sum_j A_i B_j$? Then this is simply equal to $(\sum_i A_i)(\sum_j B_j)$. So this might not be a very useful product, since it only depends on the sum of the vectors' components and not on their direction.

Comment: How is that dot product different? Why are you using two different indicies?